# Polymorphism: How do you access derived class member functions?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

Let's say we have a derived class from an abstract base class. A pointer to the abstract base class is declared in the main and allocated to the derived class through "new". How do you access the member functions of the derived class from a pointer to the base class (not from an object of the derived class)?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class clsStudent
{
public:
   virtual void display() = 0;// {cout<<"Student\n";}
};

class clsInternational : public clsStudent
{
public:
   void display(){cout<<"International\n";} 
   void passportNo(){cout<<"Pass\n";}
};

class local : public clsStudent
{
public:
   void display(){cout<<"International\n";}
   void icNo(){cout<<"IC\n";}
};


int main()
{
   clsStudent * s = new clsInternational;
   clsStudent * s2 = new local;

   s->display(); 
   s->passportNo();  //This won't work

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That goes against the entire idea of polymorphism. If you want to access a derived class function, you'll have to cast your pointer to the derived type.

Comment: The function `passNo()` is not defined in any of the classes `clsInternational`, `local` and `clsStudent`. Is it a typo? If so, what should it be?

Comment: @Oswald -Sorry about that it was supposed to be s->passportNo()

Answer (score 7):

Cheeky answer:  don't.  I mean, if you really need to, the answer to your technical question is the `dynamic_cast` operation in C++, in order to a conduct a "downcast" (cast from base to derived class).

But stepping back, this is a reasonable use case for a virtual function.  Ask yourself, what is the common meaning I want to access?

In this case, we want all students to have an identifying number.

Working source code:  http://ideone.com/5E9d5I

```
class clsStudent
{
public:
   virtual void display() = 0;// {cout<<"Student\n";}
   virtual void identifyingNumber() = 0;
};

class clsInternational : public clsStudent
{
public:
   void display(){cout<<"International\n";} 
   void identifyingNumber(){cout<<"Pass\n";}
};

class local : public clsStudent
{
public:
   void display(){cout<<"Local\n";}
   void identifyingNumber(){cout<<"IC\n";}
};


int main()
{
   clsStudent * s = new clsInternational;
   clsStudent * s2 = new local;

   s->display(); 
   s->identifyingNumber();  

   s2->display(); 
   s2->identifyingNumber();  

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: But theoretically, different derived classes can have different member variables and therefore different methods to manipulate them. What if clsInternational and local both have very different variables that have no common ground? How could we access them through their own methods from the base class?

Comment: If you really need to access a derived type, you can try the following:
`clsInternational* internationalS = dynamic_cast<clsInternational*>(s);`

Then `if (internationalS) { /* call derived class functions*/ }`